# Two RewriteRules interfering, only one works at a time

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On htaccess file with two RewriteRules, each works alone, but not both together

```
RewriteRule  ^([1-9]+)/.*/(.*) /sortir/index.php?com=page1&t=$1&l=$2 [QSA]

RewriteRule  ^([1-9]+)/([1-9]+)/.*  /sortir/index.php?com=page2&t=$1&v=$2 [QSA]
```

If I delete first, second works.
If I delete second, first works.

The link called for the first is like :

`http://example.com/33/xxxx/city` so $1 is 33 and $2 is city

The link called for the second is like :

`http://example.com/33/432/xxxx/city/yyyyy` so $1 is 33 and $2 is 432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, as anubhava notes, more details would be helpful, there are at least a few issues I can point out with your current rules.

First, reverse the order of the rules. The second rule is less general since it starts with two sections of numbers and additional sections of text. Match that first, then match the more general rule.

Second, end each rule with the L flag, otherwise processing will continue to the second rule after the first is finished.

Third, update your matches so that they don't match a slash. This forces the pattern to match the exact directory structure you're looking for rather than matching any arbitrary number of directory levels.

With those things in mind, here are some updated rules to play with:

First rule matches `http://example.com/33/432/xxxx/city/yyyy`

Second rule matches `http://example.com/33/xxxx/city`

```
RewriteRule  ^([1-9]+)/([1-9]+)/[^/]+/[^/]+/.*  /sortir/index.php?com=page2&t=$1&v=$2 [QSA, L]
RewriteRule  ^([1-9]+)/[^/]*/([^/]*)$ /sortir/index.php?com=page1&t=$1&l=$2 [QSA, L]
```

If this is not the exact rule set you need, it should at least get you closer.

Answer (score 1):

Both conditions are overlapping since this regex:

```
^([1-9]+)/.*/(.*)
```

will also match

```
^([1-9]+)/.*/(.*)
```

hence only one will fire. Why don't you explain your requirements clearly then we can help you write RewriteRule in unambiguous manner.

Comment: Still both regex will match your URIs. `^([1-9]+)/([1-9]+)/.*` and `^([1-9]+)/.*/(.*)` both will match both URIs i.e. `my_url/33/xxxx/city` and `my_url/33/432/xxxx/city/yyyyy`